# SQL Server REPLACE AND CHECK IF EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to check the string with the following scenarios in WHERE condition.

The data ProductId stored in the database can be like

`7314-3337` sometimes with - symbol and not prefixed with 19

`73143337` sometimes without symbol and not prefixed with 19

`1973143337` correct format

`197314-3337` sometimes with - symbol

I need to filter the record ProductId and the input is correct format , i.e 1973143337

```
WHERE P.ProductId=@ProductId
```

How can i filter it if the data stored in other 3 formats?

How to use the string replace(-) and prefix 19 if not exists in SQL server?

Comment: WHERE P.ProductId like '%7314%3337%'

Answer (score 3):

please check this 2 approach.
 one is very simple and second is some trick. (I think you go with second option which cover everythings)

```
declare @t table (ProductId varchar(100))

insert into @t
values
('7314-3337')
,('73143337')
,('1973143337')
,('197314-3337')
,('73683337')
,('73143338')

declare @valuetosearch varchar(100) = '1973143337'
--this is very simple , but not work in each schenerio. the second approach is fine.
--select CHARINDEX ( '19','1973143337'), SUBSTRING('1973143337',3,len('1973143337'))

--select * from 
--@t 
--where 
--replace(REPLACE(ProductId ,'-','') ,'19','') = replace(REPLACE(@valuetosearch ,'-','') ,'19','')

select * from 
@t 
where 
REPLACE( case when CHARINDEX ( '19',ProductId) = 1
then SUBSTRING( ProductId ,3,LEN(ProductId))
else ProductId
end ,'-','')
=
REPLACE ( case when CHARINDEX ( '19',@valuetosearch) = 1
then SUBSTRING( @valuetosearch ,3,LEN(@valuetosearch))
else @valuetosearch
end ,'-','')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first sanitize your data, if it is not consistent then you won't be able to get the correct results.

For prefixing with 19:

```
UPDATE foo
SET ProductId = '19' + ProductId
WHERE Left(ProductID, 2) <> '19'
```

For removing the '-':

```
UPDATE foo
SET ProductId = REPLACE(ProductId, '-', '')
```

Then you should be able to get the results you want.

UPDATE:

You could construct a CTE with the results in a single format, and then, filter that CTE:

```
WITH cte (
FormattedPID
,ProductId
)
AS (
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN LEFT(ProductId, 2) = '19'
            THEN REPLACE(ProductId, '-', '')
        ELSE '19' + REPLACE(ProductId, '-', '')
        END
    ,ProductId
FROM foo
)
SELECT FormattedPID
     ,ProductId
FROM cte
WHERE FormattedPID = @ProductID
```

Comment: I would not want to update the records. All i need is a where condition to filter all 3 formats

Comment: like `'19'+REPLACE(ProductId, '-', '')='1973143337'`

Answer (score 0):

You could make sure the column is in the correct format like this:

1. Remove the `-` by replacing it with an empty string (`197314-3337 -> 1973143337, 7314-3337 -> 73143337`).
2. Add `19` at the beginning (`1973143337 -> 191973143337, 73143337 -> 1973143337`).
3. Take 10 rightmost characters of the result and compare to the input (`1973143337 -> 1973143337, 1973143337 -> 1973143337`).

In Transact-SQL:

```
WHERE RIGHT('19' + REPLACE(P.ProductId, '-', ''), 10) = @ProductId
```

Of course, this means no index seek for you, because we are applying functions to the column.

An alternative to that would be to produce the three non-standard formats out of the input:

- cut off the initial `19` (`1973143337 -> 73143337`);
- insert the `-` (`1973143337 -> 197314-3337`);
- insert the `-` and cut off the `19` (`1973143337 -> 197314-3337 -> 7314-3337`).

In Transact-SQL:

```
WHERE P.ProductId IN (
  @ProductId,
  SUBSTRING(@ProductId, 3, 999999999),
  STUFF(@ProductId, 7, 0, '-'),
  SUBSTRING(STUFF(@ProductId, 7, 0, '-'), 3, 999999999)
)
```

This way if there is an index on `P.ProductId`, it will be used efficiently.

Both approaches assume that the length of the correct format is fixed.